# Smoothness of general fiber of flat morphism

Tags: algebraic-geometry, birational-geometry

Suppose $f: X \to Y$ is a  surjective, flat morphism of varieties over an algebraically closed field $k$ of characteristic zero. Suppose $X$ is smooth over $k$ and $Y$ is integral with fraction field $K_Y$. Is the generic fiber $X_{gen}$ automatically smooth over $K_Y$?

Comment: Usually one defines generic fiber as the fiber over $K_Y$, not general fiber. Localization of a regular scheme is regular and in characteristic zero, regular is same as smooth. So, the answer to your question is yes.

Comment: Your argument implies regularity over k. Is that equivalent to regularity over $K_Y$?

Comment: Regularity does not depend on the field.